# how to display category name for c and x from table category without using self join?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, stored-procedures

I work in sql server 2014 I need to get categories c and x without using self join.

But, I don't know how to do that.

**My data sample**

```
create table #category
 (
 categoryc  int,
 categoryx int
 )
 insert into #category(categoryc,categoryx)
 values
 (19,20),
 (50,75),
 (80,70)
    
 create table #categorydetails
 (
 categoryid  int,
 categoryname nvarchar(300)
 )
 insert into #categorydetails(categoryid,categoryname)
 values
 (19,'bmw'),
 (20,'mercedees'),
 (50,'feat'),
 (75,'toyota'),
 (80,'mazda'),
 (70,'suzoky')
    
    
 select d1.categoryname as categoryc, d2.categoryname as categoryx
 from #category c
 left join #categorydetails d1 on d1.categoryid=c.categoryc
 left join #categorydetails d2 on d2.categoryid=c.categoryx
```

expected result

[image: display category c and x without self join]

Comment: What's wrong with the query you're already using? It's returning the results you expect. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=5d6cf34ce78cb1260f6a7dd033913c5e

Comment: [dup on MS Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/717498/how-to-get-categories-c-and-x-from-table-category.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be done using `CROSS APPLY`?

```
 SELECT
 d1.categoryname AS categoryc
 ,d2.categoryname AS categoryx
 FROM #category c
 CROSS APPLY #categorydetails AS d1
 CROSS APPLY #categorydetails AS d2
 WHERE d1.categoryid=c.categoryc and d2.categoryid=c.categoryx;
```

By the way, in your query there is no self join.
Self join is when you do `TableA AS Ta1 Join TableA AS Ta2 on Ta1.x = Ta1.y`.
In your query you are simply doing two join between category and details on two different fileds.

Comment: This is definitely a self-join: `CROSS APPLY` is not necessary here, it's just a `CROSS JOIN`, and if you go through the commutation logic you will see that `d1.categoryid=d2.categoryid` in other words you may as well have written this as a normal `JOIN ... ON.. `

Comment: I agree. I was trying to provide ahmed with an alternative... ^__^